Error: The method add(Shape) in the type ArrayList<Shape> is not applicable for the arguments (Shape.Rectangle)
I'm trying to add a new shape to an ArrayList<Shape>, but I'm getting an error

The method add (Shape) in the type ArrayList<Shape> is not applicable for the arguments (Shape.Rectangle)

Shape.Rectangle is a custom class I wrote. The arguments for it are:
Rectangle(String name, Double length, Double width)

I get this error for the circle and triangle as well.
If I change the ArrayList type to Object instead of Shape, the create() method works. However, the method display() stops working.
This is my code:
public static void create(ArrayList<Shape> list) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Create shape objects using data from an input file
    File dataFile = new File("./src/shape/dataFile.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(dataFile);
    
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String shapeType = scan.nextLine();
        if (shapeType.equals("Rectangle")) {
            list.add(new Rectangle(scan.nextLine(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble()));
        }
        else if (shapeType.equals("Circle")) {
            list.add(new Circle(scan.nextLine(), scan.nextDouble()));
        }
        else if (shapeType.equals("Triangle")) {
            list.add( new Triangle(scan.nextLine(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble()));
        }
        
    }
    scan.close();
}

public static void display(ArrayList<Shape> list) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Shape shape = list.get(i);
        String name = shape.getName();
        Double area = shape.area();
        
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(area);
        }
    }

If i change the ArrayList type to Object instead of Shape, the create() method works. However, I receive errors in the display() method when trying to getName() and area().
Edit:
The code for Shape and Rectangle is:
abstract class Shape {

/**
 * The name of this shape
 */
private String name;

/**
 * Default constructor
 * Creates a Shape instance with a default name such as "Shape"
 */
public Shape() {
    this.name = "Shape";
}

/**
 * Second constructor
 * Given a name, creates a Shape instance with the name
 * @param name Name of the new shape
 */
public Shape(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Retrieves the name of this shape
 * @return Returns the name of shape
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * Given a name, changes the name of this shape to the new name
 * @param newName New name of the shape
 */
public void setName(String newName) {
    this.name = newName;
}

/**
 * Returns the area of this shape
 * @return Return of the area of shape
 */
abstract double area();

/**
 * Compares this with some other object
 * This method overrides the java equals method
 * @param obj A reference to some other object
 * @return true if some other object is equal to this shape, false otherwise
 */
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == this.name) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Represents this shape as a string literal
 * This method overrides the Java toString method
 * @return A string representation of the shape
 */
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + this.name;
}



/**
 * Rectangle Subclass
 */
public static class Rectangle {
    
    /**
     * Instance variables
     * Name, length, and width of shape.
     */
    private String name;
    private Double length, width;
    
    /**
     * Default Constructor
     * Creates a default rectangle instance.
     */
    public Rectangle() {
        this.name = "Rectangle";
        this.length = 1.0;
        this.width = 1.0;
    }
    
    /**
     * Second Constructor
     * Given a name, a length, and a width, creates a rectangle instance with the name, the length, and the width.
     * @param name, length, width Create a rectangle with these arguments
     */
    public Rectangle(String name, Double length, Double width) {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }
    
    /**
     * getName
     * Returns the name of this rectangle
     * @return name Return name of this rectangle
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    /**
     * setName
     * Given a name, replace the name of this rectangle
     * @param newName Name to replace the original name of this rectangle
     */
    public void setName(String newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    }
    
    /**
     * getLength
     * Returns the length of this rectangle
     * @return length
     */
    public Double getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    
    /**
     * setLength
     * Given a length, changes the length of this rectangle to the new length.
     * @param newLength
     */
    public void setLength(Double newLength) {
        this.length = newLength;
    }
    
    /**
     * getWidth
     * Returns the width of this rectangle
     * @Return width
     */
    public Double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    
    /**
     * setWidth
     * Given a width, changes the width of this rectangle to the new width
     * @param newWidth
     */
    public void setWidth(Double newWidth) {
        this.width = newWidth;
    }
    
    /**
     * Area
     * Returns the area of this rectangle
     * @return area
     */
    public Double area() {
        double area = this.length * this.width;
        return area;
    }
    
    /**
     * Equals
     * Compares this rectangle with some other object.
     * @param obj Reference object to compare to
     * @return true if some other object is equal to this rectangle, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        
        if(obj == this.name) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * toString
     * Represents this rectangle as a string literal.
     * @return A string representation of this rectangle
     */
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + this.name;
    }
}


Show the definition of Shape and Rectangle.

@OhmsLaw It looks like you are creating an inner static class Rectangle of the outer class Shape (but difficult to say since the source code is not complete). If you don't know what a static inner class is or what you do with these, do not define classes inside other classes.

The list expects arguments of class Shape, however you are passing Rectangle.
You might want to make Rectangle, Circle and Triangle classes to inherit from Shape.

I extended to Shape for Rectangle, Circle, and Triangle and it works. Thank you!!
